# Silverlight: usercontrol-collection

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

Hey
I want to have a usercontrol that exist out of a collection of other usercontrol

something like this:

```
<my:foocol>
<my:foo />
<my:foo />
<my:foo />
</my:foocol>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the collection control?

Comment: It the control should know about the children and there is a checked state and there should only be 1 checked at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight you have several controls that can contain a collection of child user controls.

One option is the [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and another is the various List boxes derived from the [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class.

The StackPanel will either fill itself with the child controls horizontally or vertically, while the list boxes will normally display a vertical list of items that can be selected (but this can be overriden).

You also have the WrapPanel that behaves like a horizontal StackPanel that starts on a new line when overflowing. The WrapPanel is available in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).